# display percentage of discount on product list and product view page in magento

Tags: catalog-price-rules, promotions

[image]We used "Promotions > Catalog price Rule " to give discounts for all products in our site.

for some category products we gave 20 % off and for some products we gave 10 % off.

i want to display percentage of discount on "product list " and "product view page" as like below

" [20 off]%"

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can get the discount percentage.
Let's say `$_product` is the current product instance:

```
<?php 
$originalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
$finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
$percentage = 0;
if ($originalPrice > $finalPrice) {
    $percentage = ($originalPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $originalPrice;
}

if ($percentage) {
    echo $this->__('You save %s', $percentage . '%');
}
```

for the product list you can integrate this in the `foreach` loop that lists all products and on the product view page you can add it anywhere.

Comment: it will work only simple product type

Answer (score 1):

use it

```
<?php // Display Discount percents start ?>
  <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('MRP:') ?></span>  <?php echo  $_price1= $_product->getPrice() ;?><br>
  <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Price:') ?></span> <?php echo $_finalPrice1= $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ;  ?>
     <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('You Save:') ?></span><?php echo $_savingPercent==$_price1-$_finalPrice1; ?>%
    <?php if($_finalPrice1 < $_price1): ?>
    <?php $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice1 / $_price1)*100); ?>
        <p class="special-price yoursaving">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('You Save:') ?></span>
            <span class="price">
                <?php echo $_savingPercent; ?>%
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // Display Discount percent end ?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on null