# how to display name of catalog price rule in product view page in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created catalog price rule in admin, but catalog price rule name not displaying in product view page.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Once you created catalog Price rule, you must click on "**Apply rules**" button to apply those rules. then clear cache once....

[image]

Comment: Hi,  apply rules button clicking but in product price page only price is changed,but  it not shows catalog price rule name.Can you plaese help me?

Comment: @DileepKumar so discounts are displaying in product view page , but it not showing the `catalog price rule name` in product page ?

Comment: ok sir, how to discounts are displaying in product view page?

Comment: @DileepKumar can you please tell clearly, are discounts are not displaying in product page ?

Comment: in add to cart button above my price shows these $100.00  $72.00 but here below not show 10% offer message not displayed.Can you please help me?

Comment: so you are telling both original & discount prices are displaying , but its not showing `how much percent discount` ?

Comment: yes sir,not showing how much percent discount?

Comment: @DileepKumar follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/display-percentage-of-discount-on-product-list-and-product-view-page-in-magento) and [link2](http://www.customy.com/blog/show-product-discount-percent-in-magento/)

Comment: I have follow link2 sir its shows $100.00  $72.00  You Save: 28% but it not shows 10% Discount.Can you please help me sir?

Comment: @DileepKumar are you looking for [link3](https://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/how-to-display-discount-percentage-for-special-price-in-magento/)

Comment: I will try sir after i told what output will come?

Comment: Rule Name *

20% offer
Description

20% offer 
Status *

Customer Groups *
NOT LOGGED INGeneralWholesaleRetailer
From Date

11/17/2017
 
To Date

11/25/2017
 
Priority

1
in admin create catalog price rule the above  rule name not displayed sir.Discount percentage successfully completed, but my aim is catalog price rule name displaying in replace of discount percentage sir.Please help me sir?

Comment: @DileepKumar please update the question with this requirement and mention clearly : `you want to display name of catlog price rule`

Comment: yes sir,  i want o display name of catalog price rule?

Comment: sorry sir i have problem with communication skills,but your respond my question  immediately.Thank you very much sir.Please help me?

Comment: how to display name of catalog price rule in product view page.Can you please help?

Comment: @DileepKumar please click on `edit` button below the question & mention this in question....i will check after some time.... hopefully someone else will help you.....

Answer (score 0):

That's true, it is not default Magento behavior to display the price rule name on the frontend of the website.

One way to achieve this could be:

```
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite(); // Get current website context.
$product = $this->getProduct(); // The current product.

$rules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()
    ->addWebsiteFilter($website)
    ->addIsActiveFilter(1);

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $matchedProductIds = $rule->getMatchingProductIds();
    if (isset(matchedProductIds[$product->getId()])) {
        // Product has an active price rule.
        echo $rule->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi@ mizuti sir , Tell me file path?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the res
ult of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml on line 399.Please help me?

Comment: Ah I see, I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok sir, I am waiting for your updated answer

Comment: Hi@mizuti sir,I dont know how to implemented this task.Can you please help me?